# Hypothesis testing on dependent samples to identify change point

Tags: hypothesis-testing, change-point

I want to perform hypothesis tests on the correlated observations. Practically speaking, suppose there is a sequence of data points $X_n$, which could be regarded as the observations from a certain multivariate normal distribution.

My question here is that I want to test that the mean of first 10 observations is the same as the mean of the second 10 observations, also second 10 V.S. third 10, so on so forth. I am wondering if there is an existing test or distribution for the mean difference.

---

*Update:*  I have intensity data for every location of chromosomes, and the goal is to detect the change points. The algorithm is that for a fixed window size, say 20, and for each location spot, I want to test whether the mean of 10 points on the left-hand side of this spot is different from the mean of 10 points on the RHS of this spot. which takes the dependence structure into consideration.

Comment: What do you mean by "first 10" and "second 10", etc, exactly?  Are these data from a time series? Can you say more about your situation, your data, & your goals? Can you post your data? What are they?

Comment: I have intensity data for every location of chromosomes, and the goal is to detect the change points. The algorithm is that for a fixed window size, say 20, and for each location spot, I  want to test whether the mean of 10 points on the left-hand side of this spot is different from the mean of  10 points on the RHS of this spot. which takes the dependence structure into consideration.